# Inconsistent title bar reference to "featured questions"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bountied-tab

In this screenshot, when clicking on the "Featured" tab, in the window tab, it says "Bounty Questions":

[image]

Can we change that from "Bounty Questions" to "Featured Questions"? Just like when you click on the "Newest" tab, it says in the window tab, "Newest Questions":

[image]

Comment: This is specific to the `/questions?sort=featured` URL, not `/?tab=featured`.

Comment: Same goes to "Newest Tab" as seen in the edit.

Comment: The following two are also (slightly) different from what you can click on: Votes -> "Highest voted"; Active -> "Recently active". But that's not a problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This slight inconsistency has been fixed.

With you in the next build.